# Uninitialized structure members: best practice

Tags: c, initialization

In my code I have a struct like this:

```
struct fileinfo {
    /* ... */
    bool hashed;
    char hash[20];
}
```

Each function that processes a `struct fileinfo` does only read the value of `hash` if and only if `hashed` is set. My program writes a couple of these `struct fileinfo`'s into a temporary file to be used later on:

```
struct fileinfo info;

/* ... */

info.hashed = false;

/* ... */

if (fwrite(&info,sizeof info,1,m->info_file) != 1) {
     perror("Error writing to temporary file");
     return 1;
}
```

Valgrind now complains that I pass uninitialized memory to the system call `write`. What is the best practice to deal with such a case? Is it the best idea to simply `memset` the member `hash` to zero bytes beforehand?

Comment: How about writing `struct fileinfo info = { 0 };`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB This would be equal to the memset method and less feasible because in the actual code, I embed a struct stat into the struct fileinfo which I cannot control completely as I want to stay platform independent.

Comment: There is no problem with a `stat` field (or any other). If you provide an initializer, all omitted fields are `0` initialized automatically. In the contrary `{ 0 }` is **the** tool foreseen by the standard to default initialize a `struct`. `memset` is not (exactly) the same might not be suitable on some architectures if you have pointer or floating point members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually just `memset` the whole thing before using.

```
memset( &info, 0, sizeof(info) );
```

Comment: That would silence the warnings -- but if those zero bytes aren't meaningful, valgrind won't detect a bug in your software that causes it to read them. Probably not relevant in this case, but there can be advantages to leaving memory truly uninitialized.

Comment: @Keith If I don't zero out this space, valgrind would complain. It's kind of a catch-22.

Comment: @KeithThompson  What is the advantage if you are passing it to a routine that could potentially be reading it?  Valgrind is pretty ornery, but I don't find this behavior out of line.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Yes, it is. I'd probably zero the space because it's written to a file; you *might* want to examine the file, and making the contents consistent would be a good thing. Or you could `memset` it to some distinct value other than zero. The alternative, ignoring that particular valgrind warning, is also legitimate.

Comment: @Jim: The OP says that data *won't* be read. But consider a bug like this: `int var; if (condition) { var = 42; }; do_something_with(var);`. valgrind can detect that kind of bug -- but if you change `int var;` to `int var = 0;`, it can't, because it doesn't know that the initial `0` shouldn't be read. As FUZxxl says, it's a catch-22.

Comment: @KeithThompson I meant "It won't be read" as "My program won't attempt to interprete the data". Of couse, the unititialized data lands in a temporary file (which is immediately unlinked after creation) and will be read in again by my program.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Ah, you're right. Still, I think reading garbage data from a file into an in-memory data structure, and then not accessing the garbage after that, should be harmless. And writing it to and reading it from a file will circumvent any tool's ability to keep track of whether it's garbage or not. I'd say zero it, or set it to some distinct value, before writing it to the file. Fill it with, say, `0xEF`; then if you see a bug caused by accessing bytes full of `0xEF`, you'll know where it came from.

Comment: @Keith Looks like a sane idea. (or I could rework my program to not use temporary files...)

Answer (score 6):

Use the default initializer `{ 0 }` to automatically initialize **all** fields of your `struct` to `0`.

There is no problem with a `struct stat` field or any other field that you don't control fully. If you provide an initializer, all omitted fields are `0` initialized automatically.

`memset` is not (exactly) the same. It might not be suitable on some architectures if you have pointer or floating point fields.

If your compiler blurbs at you when you use the default iniatilizer (gcc does by default with `-Wall`) you could use a designated initializer as of C99 for a field that you know to have the same effect

```
struct fileinfo info = { .hashed = false, };
```

Comment: Using { 0 } gives a warning:  *warning: missing braces around initializer*. I don't like ignoring warnings.

Comment: @FUZxxl unfortunately that warning of gcc is completly superfluous in that case. `{ 0 }` is *the* way that the C standard provides for exactly these cases. But see my edit for a wait out of this.

Comment: @FUZxxl: The `= { 0 };` warning depends on version of GCC; 4.8.1 does not give it for: `struct xyz
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} xyz;

int main(void)
{
    struct xyz pqr = { 0 };
    struct xyz abc = { .z = 0 };
    return pqr.x + pqr.y + pqr.z + abc.x + abc.y + abc.z + xyz.x + xyz.y + xyz.z;
}`.  GCC 4.2.1 does complain about the missing initializers.

Comment: @FUZxxl: The gcc developers acknowledge that this warning is a bug. They just don't have a good fix for it yet.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, if that would be fixed in gcc, now, that would be good news.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind's complains are yours to ignore. This is a tool (*the* tool, actually), but you are the programmer and *if you know what you are doing*, you can ignore any warnings.

I wouldn't recommend it though. Many bugs are born that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
void set_file_info(struct fileinfo info, bool hashed, char *hashval)
{
  if (hashed == true){
     info.hashed = true;
     strcpy(info.hash,hashval);
  } else {
     info.hashed = false;
     memset(info.hash, 0, HASH_SIZE);   /* HASH_SIZE = 20 */
  }
}
```

Comment: or check for `hashval==NULL` and skip the `hashed` param

Comment: For some reason, I tried to add some formalism (a la OOP, but not quite) to control how the parameters are accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `{ 0 }` answers, but if you want to leave info.hash uninitialized, **don't write *that* structure**.

```
struct fileinfo izero = { 0 };
struct fileinfo *ptr = info.hashed ? &info : &zero;
if (fwrite(ptr, sizeof *ptr, 1, m->info_file) != 1) {
```